# how do i change the css property for only one row with a custom class with out removing the styles from the other rows?

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/louisverdiguel/pen/vCJFh

this is my first time here i hope i am doing it right.

### **html**

I have created a string of rows and columns with html for a client to "resemble" a spreadsheet.

### **CSS**

I have created a css class class="sale td"
within the class .

```
.sale td {border: 1px solid grey; }
```

to have a border show for each row

> **issue:** i would like to remove the border from any `<tr>` that contains a `<h2>` tag

how would i go about creating such a specific class or action with the CSS and what is this method called?

Comment: you mean, if <a> tag is there, you want to remove border for that row?

Comment: so the selecting path looks like `td ->> a ->> td ->> remove border`, well it's obviously a backwards/upwards path, CSS can't work that way (traverse back from child (this case) or back to the previous siblings (another case)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this: **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/UM2eX/2/)**

**CSS:**

```
.sale tr.no_border td {
    border: 0px !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<tr class="no_border">
  <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="top"><h2>Bottles</h2></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thank you kiran this example was the most useful i appreciate you taking the time to set up the format in the fiddler! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't go backwards like that setting styles for a tag based on tags inside it. You have to mark the `tr`/`td` with a class if it contains a `h2` in order to do this.

Edit:
An example.

*CSS*

.noborder {border:none !important}

"!important" ensures it overrides the other CSS style.

*HTML*

`<td class="noborder">`

Edit2:
Also ".sale td" in your CSS means any `<td>` inside a block (table in this case) with a class of "sale". So you don't set a class of "sale td" on your `<table>` - but just "sale"

Answer (score 0):

You can only try to add `style` tag to each row, for which you want to remove the border.
For example:

```
<td colspan="4" align="left" valign="top" style="border:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For every row you can use this css:

    .sale td {border: 1px solid grey; }

    but for the rows with <h2> in it:

    .sale tr.no-border td {
        border: 0px !important;
    }

    and your html will look like:

    <tr class="no-border">
      <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="top"><h2>Heading</h2></td>
    </tr>
```